# Utility of Field Programmable Analog Arrays

Tags: analog, development-tools, fpaa

The only FPAA-related question I can find is [THIS](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/11586/use-of-field-programmable-analog-arrays-for-analog-computation), but it doesn't really introduce me to the area.

The concept seems like a nifty thing to have as part of an analog toolkit.  I can't necessarily see implementation in deployable devices in any of my work, but I can see the possibility of some sort of quick and dirty prototyping environment, perhaps replacing bins of op amps and passives, making the electronics bench a bit more portable.   I'm wondering if this is worth pulling the trigger on this summer.

In terms of a question, do those in the know believe that such a tool can serve as sort of a very portable analog electronics bench for the right sort of prototyping jobs.

Also, I can't really tell if the FPAA has any holding power.  The main player I see is [Anadigm](http://www.anadigm.com/devkits.asp).  Are there any others?  Is one maker enough to depend on?  If this is as convenient an idea as it seems to be, why hasn't it become popular?

Lastly, can anyone recommend, from personal experience, a good toolchain/devkit?

Comment: I think FPAAs *were* used some time ago, but now nobody is using them anymore.

Comment: The most successful ones are PSOC's from Cypress, which combine an ARM core with programmable analog front ends.

Comment: Do the PSOC's provide for analog outputs from their analog components?

Comment: Yes PSOCs can implement, for example, [DACs and op amps](http://www.cypress.com/psoc/?source=CY-ENG-HEADER) and click on the 'Technology' tab