# Field programmable analog array

Tags: fpga, analog

I know and use FPGAs quite a lot between my microcontroller and external interfaces and learned to value the flexibility of this setup.

Now I am wondering whether such a thing exists for the analogue world, too: an array of opamps, filters and comparators together with routing interconnect in a single package.

I've found a sparse selection of programmable gain amplifiers and some programmable higher-order filters at mouser and digikey but nothing with an programmable interconnect.

Does such thing exists? Or are we stuck with special made analogue interface circuitry?

Comment: See discussion here: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/112076/utility-of-field-programmable-analog-arrays?lq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's called (originally enough) a Field Programmable Analog Array. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field-programmable_analog_array It was introduced about 20 years ago, and never really caught on.